# MVC with InterSystems Caché ODBMS Backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, intersystems-cache

I've been looking into using and MVC C# frontend to a Caché database backend. After looking around for a while i haven't been able to find an effective way of connecting the two together (via .edmx model generation). I know I'll need a database driver for Visual Studio 2012 to do this but i don't know where to find it.

I've been developing a few apps using MVC technology and want to keep following suit instead of resorting to using their .csp based technology.

Hopefully somebody can help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the **Cache Managed Provider for .NET** documentation:

http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBMP

The Managed Provider functionality specifically allows you to access Cache data from within .NET programs.  It's not going to be as nice as using, say, the .NET Entity Framework to do data access, plus you'll have to take InterSystems' code example with a grain of salt since they are pretty simplistic, but this should be what you need.

Comment: Yeah i had the same thought, its a shame because an ODBMS would probably go quite nicely with Entity Framework.

Comment: After contacting InterSystems directly, they told me that they are currently working on a driver to provide Entity Framework compatibility. They said that this should be available sometime next year... :(. Even though this doesn't really help now, it might help somebody in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ORM framework like Entity Framework or NHibernate to get access to Intersystems Cache so the database can be separated nicely in the data layer. I managed to make NHibernate works with Intersystems Cache works. Have a look at [here](https://gaogang.wordpress.com/2014/10/16/using-nhibernate-with-intersystems-cache-database/) if you are interested.

Comment: It's link only answer. Second, self blog/site promotion are not allowed, at least not through answer!

Comment: To save this answer from moving to be deleted, include the essential portion from the original source here!

Comment: It's not my intention to promote my blog. Sorry if it was interpreted this way. I will edit my answer so it focuses a bit more on the question itself.

Comment: No I didn't mean to that! I just shared what is correct and rules of SO!